# avoid multiple downloads of font file when using webpack and preload

Tags: html, css, webpack, fonts, preload

I have a set up where I process font files like this in Webpack (v5):

```js
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|woff2|gif)$/,
        type: 'asset/resource',
      },
```

Then I have a `fonts.css` stylesheet

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyFont';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 50 1000;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url('../../static/fonts/MyFont.woff2') format('woff2-variations');
}
```

My stylesheets are processed via `mini-css-extract-plugin`, `css-loader` and `postcss-loader`. To get better performance, I'm also preloading the font like this in my HTML template:

```html
    <link
      rel="preload"
      as="font"
      type="font/woff2"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      href="static/fonts/MyFont.woff2"
    >
```

However I end up with my font to be bundled in a filename `[hash].woff2` and used instead. This results in font being preloaded but not actually used. This also slow downs the loading since it's waiting for that `fonts.css` to finish downloading the font.

What is the best solution to this? I'd like to keep `fonts.css` file ideally but maybe the solution in this case is to inline it?